# What does the highlighted portion of this handwritten Kanji say?

Tags: kanji, handwriting

[image]

知恵袋で***いてるし…

I tried searching Google, hoping it's a phrase that might come up more often, but none of the Kanji that came up looked even remotely like the one written here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It says 聞いてるし.

[image] is 略字 (the handwritten simplified/abbreviated kanji) of 聞.

Other kanji with 門, such as 問、間、開、閉 etc., can also be simplified the same way:

[image]

Other examples of 略字:

[image]

For more about 略字, see: [Ryakuji on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryakuji)

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering if it might be a sloppily written 'mon' but the vertical line at the top had me confused - that it could be an abbreviated version hadn't crossed my mind.

Comment: @shoko I know this is an old post but I am curious, in your experience, are the 略字 above commonly used in handwriting? In other words, would a native recognize them without context? Thanks

Comment: @G-Cam 小・中学・高校生で略字を使う人はほとんどいないと思いますが、普通の大人は、特に「1第、2門、5曜、4職、12器」辺りの略字はよく使われるので、文脈なしでも分かると思います。年配の人のほうがよく使う気がします。試験・履歴書・丁寧な手紙などでは好まれません。「8戦」「10機」の略字はほとんど見たことがないですが、文脈がなくても「戦」「機」かな？って想像できそうです。でも、「9濾」「13魔」の略字は文脈がないとわからないかもしれません（私はわからないです）。

Comment: ^間違いました・・「8戦」じゃなくて「8選」って書きたかった・・

Comment: @chocolate 僕は勉強不足っすね。13魔・摩はゲームや漫画などで多用されますので知ってました。ただ、それ以外は２門しか知りませんでした。4職は両方の略が多く使われているんですか？

Comment: @Gui 両方見るような気がします。　勉強不足ではなく、こういうのって年配の人が良く使うもので、知ってれば知ってるほど年齢が上ってことだと思います… (T_T)

Answer (score 23):

This is the handwritten simplified version of [image], similar to simplified Chinese [image].

Note however that the simplified Chinese form of the [image] radical has a break, and the "divider" is a single dot-like stroke in the left corner:

[image]

Meanwhile, the 門 radical is often abbreviated in Japanese handwriting to a 略字{りゃくじ} (*ryakuji*, "abbreviated character") form.  The Japanese *ryakuji* form of 門 has the surrounding line as a single connected line, and the "divider" line in the center.

[image]

Read more about *ryakuji* [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryakuji).