# What kanji is this?

Tags: kanji, handwriting, writing-identification

So I was reading stuff on the official website of the anime 僕のヒーローアカデミア and stumbled upon this handwritten message from the original manga's author.

[image]

I cannot read the encircled part because I do not recognize the first character at all, and the second one I think is 係 but I'm not sure, either.
If I'm right about the second character, and if I squint hard enough, I can see it as 関係, but am I right? Am I even close?

If needed, the full image is in http://heroaca.com/special.html, at the very bottom of the page where the "Special Message" can be accessed.

I don't often see/read handwritten Japanese so I am not used to this.
Thanks!

Comment: Your guess is right; this simplification is called *ryakuji*. See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/43044/what-does-the-highlighted-portion-of-this-handwritten-kanji-say/43047#43047) and [this](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%95%A5%E5%AD%97)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indeed, it reads 「アニメ関係{かんけい}の皆様{みなさま}」　("***To all parties involved in animation***").

In handwriting, the "simplified" form of the radical 「門」 (called 門構{もんがま}え) shown below is quite often used particularly, but not exclusively, by adults.

[image]