# この正角な时间に : "right" can be intended as "right now" or is it just "correct"?

Tags: translation, word-choice, kanji

I have this sentence (down below) that should mean "*In this right moment*" but I'd like to say something more "*Right in this moment*"... "*right*" sould be intended as intensifier, not as adjective with the strict meaning of "*correct*".

この正角な时间に

This could be intended as I do or I'm forced to translate it differently? If yes, how?

My problem is that I can use only very simplified kanji, nothing too complex to write.

Can you help me?

---

for @droooze (thank you very much for you patience):

Something like *that* (img) could work in Japanese language, and, most important, is it actually Japanese?

[image]

---

So if I present this* I can be sure that the right line means "*right in this moment / at this very moment*", right? Even if with "*moment*" isn't intended a flashy instant but a longer moment, something more similar to the concept of "*time*"... right?

*

[image]

(The second line should mean "I am alive")

Comment: Where in the world are you getting `この正角な时间に` from? If you're trying to write *correct* (Simplified Chinese: 正确), this is written as **正確**, and 时间 is written as **時間**. **You cannot use Simplified Chinese in a Japanese text**, just like you cannot use kana in a Chinese text - this is utterly incorrect.

Comment: I'm feeling so clumsy... so you're telling me that the most simplified way to write it is the following? **この正確な瞬間に** Isn't there any way to simplify these three kanji? **確 瞬 間** I know I'm asking something blasphemous, but I'm forced to ask it, forgive me :'(

Comment: It's not *blasphemous*, it's *incorrect*, and a Japanese audience won't actually understand what you are writing. If you were using something that Japanese people commonly use as a shorthand, like that detailed [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/43044/what-does-the-highlighted-portion-of-this-handwritten-kanji-say/43047#43047), then people can actually read it.

Comment: Got it, thanks... Can I ask you the shorthanded version of the other two kanji, 確 瞬 ?

Comment: @droooze I cannot put images in comments so I edited the question to ask you a confirm about the third kanji **間**

Comment: 間 is ok (write the inside more clearly), but..what exactly is the difficulty in 確, 瞬, and 間, that you're insisting on "simplifying" them? Typing them should make no difference, and if you're *handwriting* these but finding them taking too long to write, I suggest you take the time to learn [cursive script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursive_script_\(East_Asia\)) rather than trying to simplify them on the computer screen.

Comment: I have to simplify it for a small tattoo of a friend of mine, there's no serious reason behind it  :'(

Comment: Google "David Beckham Chinese Tattoo". I heavily suggest that you find an artist who can flourish characters in that type of cursive if you want to make a good-looking "simplified" tattoo. FYI his tattoo says「生死有命富貴由天」.

Comment: The problem is that the tattoo shouldn't be more than 5cm high (it would be vertical) and the tattoer rightfully said that the three kanji I'm asking about are too complex for such a small tattoo but my friend doesn't want to touch the meaning. According to you isn't there any solution, right?

Comment: Beyond droooze's last comments, 5 cm isn't a lot of space for small Japanese characters that will 'fade' and diffuse, becoming illegible over time... give it 5 years... and in 20 years it will be totally unreadable! The tattooer is right that kanji characters are too complex on that scale, but kana with _dakuten_ ◌゙are  also problematic.

Comment: I know it's very small, but my friend is very stubborn and there's nothing I can say about it... the only thing I can do is to help her finding the easiest kanji to tattoo. However, thank you very much for your advise ^^

Comment: Well, for your exact phrasing I could only "simplify" it to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxF2p.png), so I don't think it is possible. Good luck anyway.

Comment: @droooze Ok, you're right, it seem pretty difficult to tattoo ^^' but I really like your writing, especially in the very last kanji (る) compliments! Thank you very very much for everything :)

Answer (score 2):

If you can use "right" as the meaning of "right now" in Japanese, they are ちょうど今、まさに今. So "Right in this moment" would be translated as "ちょうどこの瞬間"、"まさにこの瞬間"、"今この瞬間" and so on. You can change the word "瞬間" to "時", but if your friend want to tattoo it, I think 瞬間 is cooler.

Comment: Thank you so much... I know, but the tattooer was very strict about the complexity and my friend is very strict about the dimensions, so my hands are tied :( Can I ask you just one last confirm I added in my question?

Comment: Simplified kanji like that are not used in formal sentences, but some people use them in private sentences.

Comment: Can I ask you what kind of register does it have? I mean, it has a "serious" meaning but it's also very personal... so a private writing can fit, but it shouldn't be something like "4 me U'R 2 lazy"... I mean, if you read it you're not going to think it is written by a 12 years older boy, right?

Comment: I am not sure that I could understand your question correctly, but I think it doesn't have serious purpose, some people would want to write kanji fast and easily in private sentences.

Comment: I mean, it's not **too** informal, as an occidental abbreviation like "for" that is written "4", or "you" that becomes just "u" (expressions used mostly by adolescents)... I hope that the kanji I used are simply not suitable to a formal context, that wouldn't be a problem. On the opposite, if they're silly or funny that wouldn't be good and I will have to search for something else

Comment: I think simplified kanji is not common as occidental abbreviations you referred to. You had better not use them.

Comment: Ok :') Thank you very much for your advises. But shouldn't I use them just in the first sentence or is the second one wrong too? I mean, this* should be correct, right? * **この正確な瞬間に私 - が生きている**

Comment: I'd like to know how the same sentences look like in katakana... but I think I have to open another question for it [mumbling]

Comment: I am not sure what this phrase 正確な瞬間 means. Does "correct moment" make sense?

Comment: Yes, but it should be in the meaning of **"precise moment"** , as I asked in the main question, something like **"right now"**

Comment: As I said, the phrases in my answer are natural. We rarely use 正確な瞬間.

Comment: Sorry, I think I got confused... This **ちょうどこの時間** should be correct, right? When you told me that you don't use simplified kanji you were referring only to the last modifed kanji (間), true? Can you confirm that **私が生きている** means **"I am alive"** in real Japanese and it's not just a half-invented language?

Comment: ちょうどこの時間 makes sense, though it implies longer time than 瞬間. By the way, 时间 is kanji used in China, not used in Japan. Yes, 私が(は)生きている means "I am alive".

Comment: I wrote it like that because they linked me [here] (https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/43044/what-does-the-highlighted-portion-of-this-handwritten-kanji-say/43047#43047) and I thought that I was allowed to use the short hand version... am I not?

Comment: 时间 is different from the short hand version. It is Chinese kanji. https://cjjc.weblio.jp/content/%E6%97%B6%E9%97%B4

Comment: Oh... can I ask you how does the short hand version look like?

Comment: As for 間,  you used it in your question like ちょうどこの時間、私は生きている. I don't know how to write it by PC.