# Could someone help me make sense of the name on this image?

Tags: translation, kanji

こんにちは、小さな＊井さん
Is that a misspelling of 広, i.e. "Hiroi" (if the second kanji is "井")? Is the second kanji 女 or 井? I can't make sense of it otherwise. Cheers!

[image: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/]

Comment: It's not a name, it's just 魔女, where the inside of the 魔 has been simplified to マ.

Comment: @Leebo could you kindly link anything (a website, an article) etc. in any language where this idea of "simplifying" kanji is expanded upon?

Comment: Anyway, found https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11189280376. So that answers it, thanks.

Comment: It's listed as an example in the Wikipedia article on ryakuji https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryakuji

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/43046/9831

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the word 魔女 with a simplified version of 魔 which uses マ to represent the phonetics of it. You can read more about this kind of thing on the Wikipedia article about [ryakuji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryakuji).